# Adding float action button to a view controller inside tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, floating-action-button

I am using a custom floating action button ([Floaty](https://github.com/kciter/Floaty)) that I want to add programmatically to my UITableViewController which is inside a UITabBarController. The issue is that the bottom tab bar is overlayed on top of the floating action button.

Inside my table view controller:

```
let floaty = Floaty()
...
self.view.addSubview(floaty)
// also tried: self.tabBarController?.view.addSubview(floaty)
```

I tried setting the margins like this:

```
floaty.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 60, right: 0)
floaty.layoutIfNeeded()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

But it doesn't work.

[image]

How do I correctly place the button in the table view controller? Or at least, how do I set the bottom margin programmatically?

**EDIT:**

Also tried

```
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(floaty)
```

And at first it adds the button correctly, but when I switch tabs it reverts back to the position where is overlayed by the bottom bar.
Here:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does `Floaty` position itself or is there more code that you haven't shown us here which gets the button into the bottom right corner of the screen?

Comment: yes, it positions its self in the bottom corner

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/SUITabView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of code will solve the padding problem:

```
floaty.paddingY += tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height
```

If you want the fab to be global for all of your tabs, you should add it like here:

```
tabBarController!.view.addSubview(floaty)
```

Otherwise, if you add it to the navigationController and I assume that you have a different one for every tab, it will exist only in that navigationController's viewControllers. The same happens if you add it to self.view, because it will only exist in that view controller.

Also, if you want to hide/unhide the fab in some specific view controllers, you should use a combination of `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear/viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear` methods like here:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    floaty.isHidden = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    floaty.isHidden = true
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't implement it in your tableView,
you should add it to ur homeTabs where u have implemented ur tabs
u can neither add it by adding as an IBOutlet or just declare it as a button 
here is my code ( I have a floating button in my Contests tab )

```
  @IBOutlet weak var leaderBoardBtn: UIButton!
```

//add bottom-top-leading-trailling constraints for ur button

```
  @IBOutlet weak var leadBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

///this causes my button to float 
// this is my button's bottom's constraint to superView.bottom

and then in the viewDidLoad :

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(leadAnime(_:)),name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "animate"), object: nil)
```

then some where out of the viewDidLoad add this :

```
@objc func leadAnime(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if let  count = notification.userInfo?["top"] as? Bool{
            if count{
                leadBottom.constant = 20
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                })
            }else{
                leadBottom.constant = -100
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                })
            }

        }
    }
```

now in ur table view contorller :

```
 var scrollS :CGFloat = 0
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "animate"), object: nil, userInfo: ["top":false])

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "animate"), object: nil, userInfo: ["top":true]) }

   override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollS - scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0{
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "animate"), object: nil, userInfo: ["top":true])
        }else{
            if scrollS - scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0{
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "animate"), object: nil, userInfo: ["top":false])
            }
        }
        scrollS = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    }
    override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollS - scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0{
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "animate"), object: nil, userInfo: ["top":true])
        }else{
            if scrollS - scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0{
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "animate"), object: nil, userInfo: ["top":false])
            }
        }
        scrollS = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
```

Comment: Is this a general solution for any view or are you referring explicitly to Floaty?

Comment: yes , it's a general solution because its working on the basis of updating constraints

Answer (score 0):

You added the button on the view controller which stand below the **tab bar conntroller**:

```
self.view.addSubview(floaty)
```

So of course the tab bar will always stand above your view controller which you added the button as sub view.
Look at figure 2 in [UITabBarController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Solution as of 2020 using Swift 5 to fix position is not correct on iPhoneX (has safe area view):

```swift
var floaty: Floaty!
var shouldLayoutFloaty = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initFloaty()
}

func initFloaty() {
  ...do something with Floaty

  shouldLayoutFloaty = true
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if shouldLayoutFloaty { // use this check to prevent infinite loop of "viewDidLayoutSubviews"
            // call "tabBar.frame.size.height" in "viewDidLayoutSubviews" will return the exact height of tab bar on iPhoneX
            floaty.paddingY = tabBar.frame.size.height + 20
            shouldLayoutFloaty = false
        }
    }
```